# Escaping double quotes within a sed backreference replace

Tags: linux, sed, command-line-interface

I have the following text:

```
Matt has 11 eggs and they are brown
Helen has 23 ducks and they are black and brown
Todd has 34 quarters and they are silver
Bud has 45 pens and they are red, yellow, "greenish" and blue
```

When I run the following sed command:

```
sed -E "s/([^ ]+) has ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) and they are (.*)/\"\1\",\"\2\",\"\3\",\"\4\"/" input
```

I get this CSV:

```
"Matt","11","eggs","brown"
"Helen","23","ducks","black and brown"
"Todd","34","quarters","silver"
"Bud","45","pens","red, yellow, "greenish" and blue"
```

But what I really want is this (quotes properly escaped):

```
"Matt","11","eggs","brown"
"Helen","23","ducks","black and brown"
"Todd","34","quarters","silver"
"Bud","45","pens","red, yellow, \"greenish\" and blue"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -E 's/"/\\"/g; 
  s/([^ ]+) has ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) and they are (.*)/"\1","\2","\3","\4"/' input
```

This first replaces all `"` instances with `\"` and then performs your original command. Note how using *single* quotes around the `sed` program makes it a little more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/"/\\&/g;s/^\\"|\\(",)\\"|\\"$/\1"/g'  file
```

Convert all `"`'s to `\"`'s and then remove the `\`'s from those at the start,end and inbetween.

Comment: I think you've mistaken the OP's (flawed) CSV _output_ for the input; the real input is the free-form text at the top - unless you're suggesting running your command as an _additional_ `sed` command, _after_ the OP's.